# How to not count a slide in page number in beamer?

Tags: beamer, page-numbering

I have slides 1, 2, 3 and I only want the page number in the slides to count slide 2 and 3. So on slide 2, the page number displays `1/2`.

I followed exactly what suggested in [Beamer: \nonumber equivalent for slides?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30461/beamer-nonumber-equivalent-for-slides)
using the `noframenumbering` option. It does not do anything.

Comment: I was writing a long comment in the sense of the marmot comment-answer.  I will just add that 5-slides (pages) presentation could be even  only  single frame, thus the 5th slide could be   1/1, or the  0/0, or just the expected 5/5  depending on what you do. But nobody know if you are using overlays, frame options or any other relevant thing. So, help yourself  providing the MWE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried to find out what you might mean, but unfortunately you do not provide an MWE. Even worse, my [crystal ball](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOr3L.png) got stolen. So I can only guess what you mean. I *guess* you are confusing `frame number` with `page number`. To see this consider the MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]{}
%\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]{}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]{First frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[t]{Second frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[t]{Third frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]{Fouth frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[t]{Fifth frame}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This seems to confirm what you're saying, but the catch is that I am showing the `page` number here. Indeed, if I activate `\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]{}` instead, I get

[image]

Is this the phenomenon you're referring to?

Comment: You have your crystal ball after all. You are right about my problem. My set up was indeed page number, not frame number. After I changed it, however, my slides now show "1/1, 2/1, 3/1....." The total frame number stays at 1... any clues?

Comment: @JamesH At least in the example I posted this does not seem to happen. Do you agree? And really, I do not have my crystal ball any more. So I'd like to ask you to post a minimal example that illustrates the problem. Others will also appreciate it. (How much would others benefit from statements that come from a marmot's crystal ball? ;-)

Comment: I identified the issue. I have `\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}`. By using this package, the frame numbers get screwed. (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408198/appendixnumberbeamer-package-fails-to-count-correct-number-of-slides-in-beamer) However, I cannot find a clean solution to this issue. I dont want my appendix to have any page number (of course, I can do that manually for each slide I guess).

Comment: @JamesH Can you ask your appendix frame numbering problem as a separate question including a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and exactly which numbers you want to see on each slide?

Comment: @marmot Great crystal ball usage!