# Page numbering issues with sections/subsections in Beamer

Tags: beamer, sectioning, page-numbering, labels, pageref

I have a beamer doc in which there are a few section and subsection title slides. Those slides do not have a page number footer, and the footer page numbering do not take them into account.

In the example below, when I use `label{page:mylabel}` combined with `{page:mylabel}`, I get `p5`, however, `mylabel` is on `p2` according to the footer page number.

How can I make `{page:mylabel}` reference the correct page number at the footer (in this case `p2`)?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis} % Use metropolis theme
\title{A minimal example}
\date{\today}
\author{Matthias Vogelgesang}
\institute{Centre for Modern Beamer Themes}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \section{First Section}
    \begin{frame}{First Slide}
        Hello, world!
    \end{frame}
    \section{Second Section}
    \begin{frame}{Second Slide}
        Hello, world!
        \label{page:mylabel}
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}{Third Slide}
        A reference to p\pageref{page:mylabel}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As you can imagine, it is next-to-impossible to reproduce the issue without an explicit example.

Comment: @marmot, sorry, my bad. A MWE is added to illustrate the problem

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible that you confuse page number with frame number (see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/452863/121799 but there are most likely other threads on this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @marmot already explained, `\pageref` won't give the same numbers as shown in the footline because there the `framenumber` is shown.

However beamer has an easy method to reference frames by their frame number: You just have to label the frame with `\begin{frame}[label=mylabel]` and then you can use `\ref{mylabel}` and get the correct frame number

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[framenumber]
\title{A minimal example}
\date{\today}
\author{Matthias Vogelgesang}
\institute{Centre for Modern Beamer Themes}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \section{First Section}
    \begin{frame}{First Slide}
        Hello, world!
    \end{frame}
    \section{Second Section}
    \begin{frame}[label=mylabel]{Second Slide}
        Hello, world!
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}{Third Slide}
        A reference to p\ref{mylabel}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```